# Java - Reverse Selection Sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to create a program that does a selection sort but backwards. As in, finding the largest number and swapping it with the last. I have no idea why this isn't working.

UPDATED CODE according to comments.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;


public class Problem20 {


    public static void main(String[] args){

        int data[] = new int[10];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter 10 numbers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
        data[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        sortBig(data);

    }

    public static void sortBig(int[] data){

        int i, j, maxIndex, tmp;

          for (i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
          {
                maxIndex = i;

                for (j = i-1; j >=0; j--)
                    if (data[j] > data[maxIndex])
                      maxIndex = j;
                    if (maxIndex != i) 
                    {
                      tmp = data[data.length - 1];
                      data[data.length - 1] = data[maxIndex];
                      data[maxIndex] = tmp;
                    }             
          }



        for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++){
            System.out.print(data[r] + " ");
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: I suggest you step through the code of your program with a debugger to find out what it is really doing.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I tried this multiple times before coming here to bother people.

Comment: Have you considered actually using the value of j?  Perhaps instead of data.length - 1?

Comment: @Cameron If you are talking about in the swap, yes i tried that. I get an arrayoutofbounds exception.

Comment: Can you fix your curly braces? Your loops and if-statements are terribly hard to read and the nesting is not reflective of where it is being executed

Comment: @JustinDanielson I tried to make it more clear? I'm not sure what you mean't by fix them.

Comment: Stop being fancy and removing them. Just include them everywhere, every time. It'll prevent you from making mistakes. Your 2nd if-statement is tabbed over to the wrong scope. It's not actually being executed in the 2nd for-loop. And it's probably confusing you if you're staring at it and thinking it is right now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse your first for loop - `for(int i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

You'll also need to modify your second for loop to reflect the changes in the first for loop (the loop interior looks fine, but the loop initialization block needs to be corrected)

Comment: It still just keeps printing out what the user typed in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple test I wrote to find and make it easy to debug the code.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class Problem20 {

    @Test
    public void testSorting() {
        // passes
        assertTrue(Arrays.equals(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, sortBig(3, 2, 1)));
        // failed previously
        assertTrue(Arrays.equals(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}, sortBig(4, 3, 2, 1)));
        // create an array of unique values in pseudo random order
        int[] largeArray = new int[1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < largeArray.length; i++)
            largeArray[i] = (i * 29) % largeArray.length;
        int[] sortedArray = sortBig(largeArray);
        for (int i = 0; i < largeArray.length; i++)
            assertEquals(i, sortedArray[i]);
    }

    public static int[] sortBig(int... data) {
        for (int i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int maxIndex = i;

            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                if (data[j] > data[maxIndex])
                    maxIndex = j;
            if (maxIndex != i) {
//                int tmp = data[data.length - 1];
                int tmp = data[i];
//                data[data.length - 1] = data[maxIndex];
                data[i] = data[maxIndex];
                data[maxIndex] = tmp;
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

The simplest list I found which failed to sort was 4,3,2,1 and by debugging it I could see you were always swapping with the last element, not the last element `data.length -1` being searched `i` after making that substitution the tests worked even for a large array.